# How to called CROP intent for drawable image

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to open my drawable image in to crop intent.

But i get this error :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=android.resource:/com.example.jain/drawable/b typ=image/* (has extras) }
```

**Code:**

```
final Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse("android.resource:/com.example.jain/drawable/b");
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

    intent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");

    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

    intent.putExtra("outputX", width);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", width);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileUtils.getTempUri());
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Android does not have a crop `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/"+R.drawable.image);
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 80);  
intent.putExtra("outputY", 80);  
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

replace your package name with `your.package.name`
in your case replace it with `com.example.jain`

[How to select and crop image on android](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/) is good example for croping the image.

Then handle what you need to do in the onActivityResult() method of your Activity. Your output file should be the cropped image.

It depends on the device whether that device is support it or not.
This Intent action is not part of the internal API. Some manufacturers provide their own Gallery apps and so there is no way of knowing whether or not the user's device will recognize the Intent. **PLEASE DON'T FORGET THIS!!** :)

Comment: Now i got this error :
:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=android.resource://your.package.name/2130837505 typ=image/* (has extras) }

Comment: @Palak change 'your.package.name' with your project package name.

Comment: Yes, i just replace here dummy data

Comment: @Palak still you got this error it mean your device does not support `com.android.camera.action.CROP`.

Comment: now i change the android device 4.1.2, but still error not solved. is there any entry in Manifest.xml file for this Activity

Comment: @Palak its not related to Android Versions or API. it Depends on the Manufacturers like HTC, Samsung or Sony if they keep this Attriblute to that devices then and then only you can use CROP function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35430/discussion-between-palak-and-silentkiller)

Comment: @Palak right now i cant come to chat as its banned in office.. can come to there only after office hours.. :(